# jest testing unwanted symbols

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

i'm trying to write a **jest** test to check that there are no unwanted symbols in my url.

In my test i'm attempting to check a series of certain symbols. `(&, <, >, ", ', '/',)` however I can't figure out how to check for a `'/'` using `.toMatch`. The backslash is currently underlined in red and it's not liking how i'm writing this. Is there a better way of writing this?

```
test('check url has no unwanted symbols', () => {
const testOne = 'https://www.mytest&website.com'

        expect(testOne).not.toMatch(/& | < | > | " | ' | '/' /)

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few characters which, when they appear in a regular expression, are parsed as part of it, and which need to be escaped if you want to match that character.

Slash `/` is one of them, since it will be treated as the end of the regex unless you escape it with backslash `\`.

This should work, note that you need to remove the spaces between characters:

```js
expect(testOne).not.toMatch(/&|<|>|"|'|\//);
```

If you like, you can use the square brackets `[]` to simplify, since square brackets will match any character within the set:

```js
expect(testOne).not.toMatch(/[&<>"'\/]/);
```